# Is it possible to specify a --prefix alike option when using yum to install?

Tags: linux, yum

```
yum install subversion
```

Scripts like the above has no control of where software will be installed.

How can I specify the installation path like `--prefix` when installing from source?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not​.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? In general you can't alter where individual packages dump their files.

You can make yum install/update a different root directory by using `--installroot`, which is useful for working with e.g. chroot environments.

Comment: Probably trying to mimic the rpm `--prefix` option.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams ,that's right.